# Efficient 2D Radial Gravity Layout (Java)

Tags: java, layout, graphics, box2d, gravity

I'm after an efficient 2D mapping algorithm, and I've tried a number of implementations, but they all seem lacking.  I'm hoping the stackoverflow world can help out with some pointers to existing, tried-n-tested algorithms I could learn from.

My goal is to display articles based on the genre of writing; for the prototype, I am using Philosophy, Programming, Politics and Poetry, since those are the only four styles of writing I have.

Each article is weighted based on each category, and the home view will have each category as a header in each corner.  The articles are then laid out in word-cloud-like format, with "artificial gravity" placing each item as-near-as-possible to its main category (or between its main categories), without overlapping.

Currently, I am using an inefficient algorithm which stores arrays of rectangles to perform hit-test-and-search every time an article is added to the view, (with A* search patterns to find empty space to fill).  By approximating a single destination for all articles of the same weight, and by using a round-robin queue to pick off articles from each pool, I can achieve fresh results (arrays are sorted by weight, then timestamp), with positioning-by-relevance ("artificial gravity").

However, using A* to blindly search seems really wasteful, even with heuristics to make each article check closest to it's target marks first.  I need a more efficient way to iterate over a 2D space.

I'm wondering if a Linked-List approach might work better; rather than go searching blindly in all directions for empty space, I can just iterate through connected nodes to ask each one if it has either a) nearby free space, or b) other connected nodes to ask (and always ask the closest node first).

If there are any better algorithms available, or critiques on my methods, any and all help would surely be appreciated.

I am using gwt elemental + java in this gui, but any 2D mapping algorithm in any language will surely help.

[EDIT (request for more details)] : The main problem here is the amount of work each new addition performs; it produces noticable glitches in the ui thread, especially when there is almost no space left, as I am searching many points in a given radius for enough free space to fit the article.

If I cut the algorithm off too soon, I get blank spots that could have been filled.  If I let it run too long, the ui glitches pretty bad, and I'm sure users will hate it.

What is the fastest / most efficient way to store and modify collections of 2D space?

Comment: Could have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

Comment: Guido to the rescue! =}

Turns out I'm already doing a primitive version by storing the categories in 9-box based slots for my A* heuristics / bounds; didn't think to make it recursive though...

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer to your specific question, but have you thought about using repulsive forces between all the articles, and attracting forces to the categories. So that when you place the article, you would disable collisions, let the articles position themselves (without you searching for a place). And then after a few seconds you turn on collisions and it would "sproink" into a good uncollided position. What you have is basically a graph layout problem, repulsive forces between every article is the easiest way to do it, but there are other more efficient algorithms.

Comment: I have actually built a repulsive + attractive word cloud in actionscript which does exactly that; my problem with this method is that it often generates a lot of bounce; the user-facing view I'm going for is just statically laid out items that are in a radial, weighted pattern. I'm currently working on an OctTree system to split each layer of the graph into rectangular coordinates, and then implementing the 'gravity' by placing items in the nearest parent node, which ensures they are near where they are supposed to be. I will use repulsion+attraction to space the items after they are packed.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information to say what would make an algorithm "better."  Faster? Produces layouts that are "nicer" by some metric for quality?  Able to handler bigger data sources?

There is certainly nothing wrong with arrays, nor with A*. If they are giving acceptable results with the size of problem you are trying to solve, how can they be "wasteful?"  Linked data structures are worthwhile only if they reduce cost of frequently needed operations.

If you sharpen the problem, you're more likely to get a useful answer.

At any rate, there is an enormous literature on "graph layout" and "graph drawing."  Try searching on these terms. If you can represent your desired layout as a collection of nodes and edges, these might apply.  Many are based on simulated spring systems, which seems akin to what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I'll update the question with the problem I am specifically trying to solve.